# Remotely find wins addresses

Tags: remote-access, wins

I am needing the WINS addresses for about 150 machines or so. Some users are logged onto desktops and I would rather be able to check this information remotely than having to go look at their machine.

In short, is there a way to check what entries are in my WINS addresses tab? maybe typing in something from cmd?

Advanced TCP/IP settings -> WINS tab -> the addresses that are in the "WINS addresses, in order of use:"

I have found information using wmic to SET the addresses, but I just want to see what is currently there.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose one method would be to simply run `ipconfig` from [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

Comment: This ended up working out perfectly. I finished what I needed to do in probabaly a 1/4 of the time it would have taken me otherwise. Thanks Zoredache!